# Setup configurable site base variants in TYPO3

Tags: typo3

*Using TYPO3 >= v9, with Composer*

I am using an installation with several sites, the configuration is set up via .env (with [helhum/dotenv-connector](https://packagist.org/packages/helhum/dotenv-connector)).

Now, I have several development / test / staging installations with different domain names. It is possible to add additional "[baseVariants](https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-coreapi/main/en-us/ApiOverview/SiteHandling/BaseVariants.html)" to the site, such as

```
base: 'https://example.org'
baseVariants:
  -
    base: 'https://dev1.example.org'
    condition: 'applicationContext == "Development/Staging"'
```

But I would like to make this configurable in my `.env` file. I only want to change the `.env`, not the site configuration for every installation. And I would not like to set up another base variant for every domain name I might want to add.

Answer (score 1):

Ideally, figure out a naming scheme you can use and use this consistently where you have base domain name and some variant, e.g.

- main site: `https://example.org`
- development: `https://dev1.example.org`, `https://dev2.example.org` etc.

**.env**

```
SHORTCUT=dev1
TYPO3_CONTEXT="Development/dev1"
```

**config/sites/mysite/config.yaml**

```
base: 'https://example.org'
    baseVariants:
      -
        base: 'https://%env(SHORTCUT)%.example.org'
        condition: 'applicationContext == "Development/%env(SHORTCUT)%"'
```

(Official) documentation:

- [Environment variables can be used in the site configuration](https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-coreapi/main/en-us/ApiOverview/SiteHandling/UsingEnvVars.html).
- [Application context](https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-coreapi/main/en-us/ApiOverview/RequestLifeCycle/Bootstrapping.html#application-context)
- [Custom application context](https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-coreapi/main/en-us/ApiOverview/RequestLifeCycle/Bootstrapping.html#custom-contexts)